Function which returns coefficients of Legendre Polynomials not accurate enough
I'm trying to write a function which returns the coefficients of the nth legendre polynomial.
// store previous polynomials to make the recursive process faster
unordered_map<int, vector<double>> legendre_cache; 

// Recursive function to compute the coefficients of the nth Legendre polynomial
vector<double> legendre_polynomial(int n) { // uses Bonnet's recursion formula P_{n+1} = ( (2n+1) x P_n - n P_{n-1} )/(n+1)
    // Check if the result is already in the cache
    if (legendre_cache.find(n) != legendre_cache.end()) {
        return legendre_cache[n];
    }

    // Base cases
    if (n == 0) {
        return { 1.0 }; // P0(x) = 1
    }
    if (n == 1) {
        return { 1.0, 0.0 }; // P1(x) = x
    }

    // Get coefficients for P_(n-1) and P_(n-2)
    vector<double> Pn_minus_1 = legendre_polynomial(n - 1);
    vector<double> Pn_minus_2 = legendre_polynomial(n - 2);

        // Get the sizes of the vectors to n+1
    Pn_minus_1.push_back(0.0); // P_{n-1} gets multiplied by x
    Pn_minus_2.insert(Pn_minus_2.begin(), 0.0); // P_{n-2} needs two leading digits 
    Pn_minus_2.insert(Pn_minus_2.begin(), 0.0);

    // Calculate coefficients for P_n
    vector<double> Pn(n + 1, 0.0); // Initialize Pn with n+1 zeros

    // Using the recurrence relation to fill coefficients
    for (int k = 0; k <= n; k++) {
        Pn[k] += ((2 * n - 1) * Pn_minus_1[k] - (n - 1) * Pn_minus_2[k]) / n;
    }

    // Store the result in the cache before returning
    legendre_cache[n] = Pn;
    return Pn;
}

The algorithm works since I compared it's result with other sources up to n = 10.
However this function gets inaccurate very fast, and it's recursive nature is not doing it a favour:
Here I evaluate my polynomial and compare it to a similar function from the "boost/math"-library:
int main() {
    cout << fixed << setprecision(15);
    // Example inputs
    int n = 48;
    double x = 0.9;

    cout << "Result of my function:" << endl;
    vector<double> coeffs = legendre_polynomial(n);
    double result = 0;
    int l = coeffs.size();
    for (int i = l - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        result += coeffs[l - i - 1] * pow(x, i);
    }
    cout << result << endl;

    cout << "Result of boost library:" << endl;
    cout << boost::math::legendre_p(n, x) << endl;
    return 0;
}

My function gets less and less accurate with bigger n, until it breaks down entirely at around n = 45:
Outputs of test code:
Result of my function:
0.151876441197771
Result of boost library:
-0.106892037065314


I know from the boost website that the boost function uses the same recursive approach I did.
So assuming their function works, it should also be possible to improve mine.
Thanks for any help.

Edit 1:
To be clear I evaluated the polynomial just to demonstrate that my coefficients are wrong; I mainly need the coefficients of the polynomials (for Legendre Gauss Quadratures).
As far as I understand the functions in the library, I don't think the coefficients are ever mentioned there; the recursion formula is just being applied to a specific x-value.
And frankly I'm not yet at the level, to rewrite that code to extract the coefficients.

Edit 2:
What I meant with "The algorithm works since I compared it's result with other sources up to n = 10" is that I suspect that the function would work if it wasn't for accuracy errors. I think that errors due to rounding, division, floating points snowball because of the recursion until the function becomes unusable. (My question is about how to deal with this)

So you have a library (boost) with full source code.  What is preventing you from seeing how their function is implemented?  Then run their function in a debugger to see what is being done.

"The algorithm works since I compared it's result with other sources up to n = 10." -- That does not mean the algorithm works for all n. In fact, "this function gets inaccurate very fast," and "it breaks down entirely at around n = 45" suggest that either the algorithm or the implementation is flawed, just in a way that is not visible for small n.

Debugging your code looks like a big task for little gain, as this question is unlikely to help anyone who doesn't come up with the exact same code as you. I think you should do some more investigation to narrow down what's going wrong. For example, your output is the evaluation of a polynomial at a point. That's good for spot checking, but for debugging, you should look at and verify each coefficient. Are those accurate? Where does the inaccuracy start creeping in? Is it a faulty calculation or round-off error?

Good numerical stability (accuracy) can only be achieved through a very careful setup of your calculation to avoid small errors from adding up. (Lookup "numerical methods" and "error estimation"). So my first guess is your current implementation is just too naive and accumulates errors fast. e.g. one thing I already notice is that you divide by n every step of your loop. Pn[k] += ((2 * n - 1) * Pn_minus_1[k] - (n - 1) * Pn_minus_2[k]) / n  division is a source of numerical errors) so try to do that division only once (at the end), the same for your multiplication

Any reason to use the recursion? You even already have legendre_cache, so getting previous results is trivial.

Note that when evaluating a polynomial, one should prefer Horner's method.

Do you really want the coefficients at higher orders? Or do you wish to compute accurately the value of P_N(x) for large N? They are two very different questions!

One possible quick test would be to switch from double to long double and see if it takes longer for errors to creep in. (Sorry, the site went down the first time I was going to suggest this.)

@JaMiT you also need to check that long double is actually a higher precision that double - GCC will do true 80 bit long double, MS definitely doesn't (and has been unable to since v6.00) and Intel will only do so if you enable specific precision options (and not by default).  Fighting against N! a few extra bits of precision only buys you a couple more polynomials before it croaks.

@MartinBrown "Fighting against N! a few extra bits of precision only buys you a couple more polynomials before it croaks." -- My point is not that long double is a fix. My point is that if a few extra bits of precision buys you a couple more polynomials before it croaks, then the likely suspect is the precision (rather than a logical flaw). The point that long double could be the same precision as double is valid.

Martin Brown commented "Fighting against N!" -- Is there an N! in the code? That would make precision loss likely. However, I don't trust malfunctioning code to tell me what it is intended to do. So I stuck to the text, which does not mention factorials. In fact, it mentions almost nothing significant about your algorithm (just "returns the coefficients of the nth legendre polynomial" and "works"). No mention of which approach you are using, not even a reference with formulas. Overall, more text describing the situation would be beneficial.

Are you sure that actually finding coefficients - or even values - of Legendre polynomials is actually the best way of doing Gauss-Legendre quadrature? At the end of the day you are trying to find the roots of these polynomials (plus weights based on their gradients there). So I suspect that this is actually an XY-problem, albeit rather an interesting one.

The terms in your sum (polynomial coefficient times x^k) run something like 0.114567 0 -109.131 -0 17281.5 0 -1.08811e+06 -0 3.63566e+07 0 -7.46037e+08 -0 1.02638e+10 0 -1.00312e+11 -0 7.25181e+11 0 -3.99276e+12 -0 1.71069e+13 0 -5.79457e+13 -0 1.56963e+14 0 -3.42692e+14 -0 6.05831e+14 0 -8.68636e+14 -0 1.00858e+15 0 -9.43644e+14 -0 7.04902e+14 0 -4.14218e+14 -0 1.87115e+14 0 -6.26672e+13 -0 1.46486e+13 0 -2.13233e+12 -0 1.45463e+11. There is simply massive positive/negative cancellation to get a final answer of about -0.1

@haifisch123 - could you clarify your purpose for wanting the Legendre polynomials? Depending on what you want to do with them it may be simpler just to solve the Legendre equation numerically by finite differences.

I don't think you can compute the value of a Legendre's polynomial at a given point like you do, i.e. by directly using the coefficients of the polynomial. Indeed you will face numerical errors since a double can't cope with the multiplication of x with a "huge" coefficient when the order of the polynomial is big.
Instead, you can directly rely on the three-term recurrence relation of these polynomials in order to compute the value at a given point:
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <boost/math/special_functions/legendre.hpp>

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) 
{
    std::cout << std::fixed << std::setprecision(15);

    int    n = argc>=2 ? atoi(argv[1]) : 48;
    double x = 0.9;
    
    double p0=1;
    double p1=x;
    for (size_t k=1; k<n; k++)  
    {
       double tmp = ( (2*k+1)*x*p1 - k*p0) / (k+1);
       p0=p1;
       p1=tmp;
   }

   std::cout << "Result of my function:" << std::endl;
   std::cout << p1 << std::endl;

   std::cout << "Result of boost library:"    << std::endl;
   std::cout << boost::math::legendre_p(n, x) << std::endl;
    
   return 0;
}

Possible output:
Result of my function:
-0.106892037065314
Result of boost library:
-0.106892037065314


The recurrence algorithm looks to be OK but the numerical accuracy is not. Your problems with accuracy come from the recurrence relation for Legendre polynomials being rather unfriendly.
// uses Bonnet's recursion formula P_{n+1} = ( (2n+1) x P_n - n P_{n-1} )/(n+1)

Rearranging this to make the numerical precision problem more obvious:
P_{n+1} = ((2n+2-1)xP_n/(n+1) - (n+1-1)P_{n-1}/(n+1)

P_{n+1} =  (2 - 1/(n+1))xP_n - (1 - 1/(n+1))P_{n-1}

P_{n+1} =  (2xP_n - P_{n-1}) - (xP_n - P_{n-1})/(1+n)

You have already lost some precision computing P_3 since there is inevitable rounding error from 1.0/3 (and likewise for any non power of 2). You can with a bit of care work the recurrence into a form that consists of the main term 2xP_n-P_{n-1} and a much smaller correction to it but that only buys you a bit of time because n! gets big so very quickly. The fundamental problem that you have here is that IEEE754 double precision cannot represent these coefficients accurately enough beyond a certain quite modest N.
You may want to take a look at how boost actually does it for inspiration.
You are between a rock and a hard place if you want the coefficients to high accuracy for larger N because you have an implicit computation of N! You can put off the evil day by separating out the division by N out and allowing the coefficients to grow in magnitude whilst keeping track of the normalisation.
That will only get you so far though with a double precision representation. IEEE754 numbers only have a limited precision mantissa of 53 bits which simply isn't sufficient to represent these coefficients accurately enough for your needs.
Back of the envelope suggests serious loss of precision from n=20 onwards. Int64 doesn't give you any improvement at all since although you have more bits to play with you have lost the 2^p exponent that is implicit in floating point encoding. Int128 would take you up to about n=34.
The other thing that is worth mentioning is that your evaluation of the polynomial from the coefficients is inaccurate and so doing you no favours. pow(x,3) is slow and already pretty dodgy compared to x*x*x.
It looks to me like you are storing your coefficients with the highest power first. Quoting the original code using pow(x,n) here are two alternatives with increasing accuracy of evaluation and improved speed.
double result = 0;
int l = coeffs.size();
for (int i = l - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    result += coeffs[l - i - 1] * pow(x, i);
}

// alternative brute force evaluation form (least changes to code)

double xn[NMAX], result = 0;
int l = coeffs.size();
xn[l-1] = 1;
for (int i = l - 2; i >= 0; i--) x[i] = x*xn[i+1]; // x^n x^n-1 ... x^2 x 1
for (int i = 0; i < l ; i++) {
    result += coeffs[i] * xn[i];
}

// I think the order of your coefficients is highest power first.
// I much prefer the coefficient ordering  1,x,x^2 myself

// but it should really be replaced by Horner's method which can make good
// use of SIMD fma instructions and is both faster and more accurate as a result. 

double result = coeffs[0];
int l = coeffs.size();
for (int i = 1; i<l; i++) {
    result = x*result+coeffs[i];
}
// assumes coeffs[0] contains term in x^(l-1)

As an aside depending on what it is you are trying to do you may be better off looking at Chebyshev polynomials which are altogether more user friendly and have a much wider application literature.

I have not had a check on Boost implementation but I would bet that polynomial evaluation in this case is directly done with the recurrence relation without using the polynomial coefficients.
